# a little trouble with mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

my codes are working correctly but in the change of requirement.

i need to keep current `active class` active which is removed **again i mouseover at active `<li>`**

i am not good in JQuery so can somebody help doing this??

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.form').on('mouseover', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
li.active .btncss, .btncss:hover {
    color: #FFAE00;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li{display:inline}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
<li class="active"><a href="#within" id="within" class="btncss form">With In City</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#full" id="full" class="btncss form">Full Day Hire</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#half" id="half" class="btncss form">Half Day Hire</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#inter" id="inter" class="btncss form">InterCity Hire</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `addClass` instead of `toggleClass`.

[`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

[`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

*It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements.*

Try this:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.form').on('mouseover', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
li.active .btncss,
.btncss:hover {
  color: #FFAE00;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="active"><a href="#within" id="within" class="btncss form">With In City</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#full" id="full" class="btncss form">Full Day Hire</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#half" id="half" class="btncss form">Half Day Hire</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#inter" id="inter" class="btncss form">InterCity Hire</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `active class` are not adding on `siblings` kindly check this

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me..When active class should be assigned to which elements ? And when not ?

Comment: sorry for it should work as it doing in my code curruntly but when select any one of them then  again hovering that `<a>` should not remove active class form `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your question -- do you want the `<li>` that is originally active to be reset as active on `mouseout`? To do this, you need to record what was originally active and add a `mouseout` handler:

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var originally_active = $('li.active');
  $('a.form').on('mouseover', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
        $('a.form').on('mouseout', function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            originally_active.toggleClass('active');
        });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
li.active .btncss, .btncss:hover {
    color: #FFAE00;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li{display:inline}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
<li class="active"><a href="#within" id="within" class="btncss form">With In City</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#full" id="full" class="btncss form">Full Day Hire</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#half" id="half" class="btncss form">Half Day Hire</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#inter" id="inter" class="btncss form">InterCity Hire</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `active class` are not adding on `siblings` kindly check this